# Publishing Error in Visual Studio 2010 (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to create an simple database-driven application in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2010. It worked correctly while i tested in the visual studio environment. But, when i published it, installed and ran in the same computer. It didn't open. And when i saw the error details it was like this:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: billingsystem.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5046c06e
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4a275e65
  Problem Signature 07: 1e65
  Problem Signature 08: 85
  Problem Signature 09: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
```

PS: I run Windows 7 Pro. and I used a MSACCESS 2007 Database for my application. And Builded the executable (or published) using the Same Visual Studio I was developing in.

Comment: Check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason why your application didn't open is because (*maybe*) the `System.Data.dll` was not found on the system (*or was not included during the publishing*).

When I deploy my application, I always build a separate project file for the `SETUP`. Because `Publish` is really called `Click Once`, which is useful, but of course **it can't handle** complicated stuff like drivers, registry entries, install location, and other stuff.

Here's a good tutorial to create **[`SETUP for deployment on your Application`](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I will apply these. But what i actually think is, the `MSACCESS database` is the problem. I also saw some errors like File Not Found in `C:\UserData\Temps\....\.<somefile>` When i tried to debug the installed application with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: the system cannot find your database.

Comment: Then, would your previous solution help?

Comment: For me, yes. Because when you create setup project, it will include all the dependencies in your project, including `database`, or any other files.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already fixed it, but just in case I found the solution to my problem and potentially is related to yours, the connection string of one of the dataadapters was hardcoded and it worked when I ran it using vs because the database was copied to the temp file, but it wouldnt work when I ran the published version. So, configuring the dataadapter correctly was all I needed to do.